# React-Native format clipboard data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my RN application, I had to use clipboard. I copied data to clipboard using `Clipboard.setString()`.

Since it accepts a string, I had to stringify my JS object. So now the clipboard is like this.

```
"bicSwift":"PAYRGB20XXX","accountNumber":"00024147","partnerRef":"examplebank","sortCode":"040052","iban":"GB94PAYR04005200024147"}
```

I want to format this to something like this.

```
bicSwift:PAYRGB20XXX
accountNumber:00024147
partnerRef:examplebank
sortCode:040052
iban:GB94PAYR04005200024147
```

Is this possible??

Comment: are you looking to convert string back to an object? you can use `JSON.parse(string)` to get an object from json string. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: I want to remove these things from the string. { } " " :

Comment: `let keys =Object.keys({"bicSwift":"PAYRGB20XXX","accountNumber":"00024147","partnerRef":"examplebank","sortCode":"040052","iban":"GB94PAYR04005200024147"});`

Comment: you can use `string.replace` method with regex to remove the unwanted characters from string

Comment: @Shashika what will be the format of expected output data? Is it has to be `string`, `object`?

Comment: I have answered to the question. Is it correct?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity on input & output data types. Please be clear when you ask questions so people on SO don't have to guess.

Answer (score -1):

I used map() on my object as this and set the text as I wanted.

handleCopy = async () => {

```
    const { accountDetails } = this.props;

    let formattedDetails = '';
    Object.keys(accountDetails).map((key) => {
      formattedDetails += `${key}: ${accountDetails[key]}\n`
    });

    await Clipboard.setString(formattedDetails);
  }
```

Now I get the answer as I want like this.

```
bicSwift: PAYRGB20XXX
accountNumber: 00024147
partnerRef: examplebank
sortCode: 040052
iban: GB94PAYR04005200024147
```

But, My map() doesn't return anything. Is it wrong?